# reading a csv file cannot open the connection

Tags: r

I'm using R for the first time.

I am trying to read a csv file with the line of code below,

> XY <<- read.csv('C:/myfile_L.csv',header = F)

The error message I get is,

Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'C:/myfile_L.csv': No such file or directory

I thought this should be quite easy but I can't seem to get it to work. The file does exist & the path is correct, I can read it using Python.

Comment: The "no such file or direcctory" is the important part.  You tell us the file exists and the path is correct, but R disagrees. Are you sure it's there? Are you sure you don't have a typo in the name? Have a look at `list.files('C:/')` to see what files R sees under `C:/`.

Comment: @mHelpMe Could you replace / with // and try it? read.csv('C:\\myfile_L.csv',header = F). There could also be an issue with your working directory, but // should work anyway

Comment: You can also test in Windows: open up a command prompt (type `CMD` in the start search menu) and try the command `head C:/myfile_L.csv`. Do you see the first few rows of your CSV file, or an error?

Comment: Why did you use `<<-` instead of `<-`?

Comment: Type this into R: `file.choose()` and then using the dialog that comes up  navigate to and choose the file.  Now copy the output from `file.choose` into your `read.csv` statement.

Comment: ah I apologies to everyone. When I copied the path from python it appears i fat fingered an extra letter